# Limiting line length on a .pdf file (converting to a different file type)

Tags: pdf

I recently bought an e-book and would like to limit the row size to a specific number of characters (`84ex`), so I don't have to move my head while reading it on a widescreen monitor.

I was led to believe you can't change that with Adobe Acrobat Reader, I started thinking I'd just convert the .pdf file into html markup, and work from there. I used [this site](http://www.zamzar.com/convert/pdf-to-html/) in order to covert my file, but now all the text is in `<span>` tags, making it impossible to format.

Can anyone recommend a way to do this, in order to make my reading easier? (I want to change background, font, text color and line-width).

Comment: Some OCR software can convert PDF to something editable (e.g. HTML or .docx). The conversion may be of bad quality though, depending on the software and the PDF.

Comment: If the PDF was properly created, you *can* reflow its contents with Acrobat Reader.